# print all odds values from 1 up to 20 on separates line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print all odds values from 1 up to 20 on separates line

```
for h in range(1, 20):
    if(h % 2) != 0:
    print("h =", h)
```

Comment: OK, but what is your question?

Comment: That's a working code if you correct your indentation.

Comment: Note that the indentation was introduced by an editor who is not the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but just make sure you fix your indentation. I'm not quite sure what help you need with this, but if it's formatting you want this:

```
for h in range(1, 20):
    if(h % 2) != 0:
        print("h = %d" % (h))
```